# Question on Spring Kafka Listener Consumer Offset Acknowledgement

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have created the below consumer factory.

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setAutoStartup(autoStart);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
    
    return factory;
}
```

The Kafka listener is given below.

```
@KafkaListener(id= "${topic1}" ,
            topics = "${topic1}",
            groupId = "${consumer.group1}", concurrency = "1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeEvents1(String jsonObject, @Headers Map<String, String> header, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        LOG.info("Message - {}", jsonObject);
        LOG.info(header.get(KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID) + header.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC)+String.valueOf(header.get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET)));
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
```

In the consumer factory, I did not set  `factory.setBatchListener(true);` **My understanding is that the above listener code is called for each message as it is not a batch listener. That is what the behavior I saw. In the batch listener, I get a list of messages instead of the message by message.**

As the listener is not batch-based, the `acknowledgment.acknowledge()` is going to have the same behavior for **MANUAL**, Or **MANUAL_IMMEDIATE**. Is that the correct understanding?

I referred to the below material.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `MANUAL`, the commit is queued until the whole batch is processed; this is more efficient, but increases the possibility of getting redeliveries.

With `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, the commit occurs right away, as long as you call it on the listener thread.

Comment: If the listener container factory is not batchListener, still the messages are batched with MANUAL ack mode? How the messages are polled though the listener is not a batch lsitener? If the listener container factory is not a batch listener, then we get message by message from the topic, and the acknowledgment is done after the message is received.

Comment: We poll the consumer and receive a batch of records; with batch mode you get the whole batch in one call. With record mode, you get them one at a time; the offsets are committed either after the batch is all processed (MANUAL) or immediately (MANUAL_IMMEDIATE).

Comment: But in my code, I set the ack mode as MANUAL and called acknowledgment.acknowledge() in the listener once I receive a message. The offset is committed. That means though the entire batch is not processed with MANUAL ack mode,  it will commit the offset once we call acknowledgment.acknowledge(). Is that correct understanding?

Comment: No; please re-read my answer and comment. The offset is NOT committed at that time, only after the last record in the batch has been processed are all the highest offsets for each partition in the batch are committed. You can see the commit activity by setting the `commitLogLevel` container property to INFO (it's DEBUG by default). Perhaps you are confusing committed offset and position.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. I got your point. I tested the code with MANUAL and MANUAL_IMMIDIATE. For my use case, I want to receive record by record and commit the offset once I process the record. I am going with RECORD ack mode as that suits for my usecase.

Comment: Yes; manual acks are rarely needed and only complicate the listener code.